# pac command -> .NET location: Not found

Tags: .net

I'm trying to follow a tutorial for creating my first component - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/component-framework/implementing-controls-using-typescript?tabs=before

I **install both the .net sdk** ( dotnet-sdk-8.0.203-osx-x64.pkg ) and **runtime** ( dotnet-runtime-8.0.3-osx-x64.pkg ) , and then I **install the power app cli** in visual studio code as well as in global.

But when I run this command

```
pac pcf init --namespace SampleNamespace --name LinearInputControl --template field --run-npm-install
```

I got the following error

```
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /Users/xyz/.dotnet/tools/pac
Architecture: x64
App host version: 8.0.3
.NET location: Not found

Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=osx-x64&os=osx.14&apphost_version=8.0.3
```

Here is my .net version

```
dotnet --version
8.0.203
```

And here is my .net info

```
dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.203
 Commit:            5e1ceea679
 Workload version:  8.0.200-manifests.4e94be9c

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  14.4
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.203/

.NET workloads installed:
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
  Version:      8.0.3
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       9f4b1f5d66

.NET SDKs installed:
  8.0.203 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/Users/xyz/dotnet]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

When I check my path, I saw it included the following path

```
:/Users/xyz/dotnet:/Users/xyz/.dotnet/tools
```

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sdk contains the runtime, instead of using the runtime I installed, I reuse the runtime by changing my DOTNET_ROOT

```
export DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/local/share/dotnet
```